# xml file based website

Tags: html, xml

I have an XML File, looking a bit like this:

```
<Page Id="1" OrderIndex="1" Name="Page1" IdPageTemplate="1">
  <Text Id="2" OrderIndex="1" Name="head" HtmlFileName="head.html" IdPageElementTemplate="2"/>
  <Text Id="3" OrderIndex="1" Name="content" HtmlFileName="content.html" IdPageElementTemplate="3"/>
</Page>
```

I need to create a website based on this file. Now, I dont have any clue were to start. 
Does anyone know were to start, or knows somekind of CMS that will help. Any information on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking where to start with the task of creating a website? Or are you asking how to approach parsing the descriptor file?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I know how to build a website, just don't have any expirience with XML files.. So im asking how to approach the xml

Answer (score 0):

This file appears to describe an HTML document in its entirety, from the head element to its body content. It also defines an Id, which could represent a unique id (like a database id column), but you'd want to do some validation server side to ensure its uniqueness if you treat it as such.

Your general approach would be to write a server side method that loads the file and iterates through the nodes looking for the HTML element definitions. Search Google or this site for how to parse XML.

As you retrieve the elements, build a string that will be your HTML output. One strategy would be to try and create the entire raw HTML and then spit that out as the response to the page request. You haven't stated what framework, platform, and language you're working with, so there's not much I can give in the way of specific examples.

In my shop we use ASP.NET MVC and C#. So I would likely just get the salient parts of the elements and fill an existing View template with the content. As in, I have a HEAD element already defined in the View, so I'd rather use that than the file's data. But in my BODY I'd have a placeholder for the main content, and I'd populate that placeholder with the data in the respective element in the file.

You've only shown a small part of the XML, so there may be more structure that would suggest a different approach.

The short of it is that you'll create a set of server side processes that you call to read the data from the file, and fill placeholders in your template page with that data. Hope that helps.